# Can the Android Jelly Bean camera app be set to take pictures as they appear on screen?

Tags: camera, 4.2-jelly-bean

After my most recent Android update, the camera app has changed the way pictures are framed. While they used to be taken as they appear on the screen, they are now stored with "extra space", i.e., as if zoomed out further than was apparent while taking the photo. This is very annoying when I'm trying to frame a shot in some particular way. To get the photos I want I am now forced to take the picture, hope for the best, and then crop it to how I wanted it to be framed in the first place.

Has anyone found a way to change this back to "normal" what-you-see-is-what-you-get style photo shooting?

Comment: This is really annoying. I've tried all camera options but it's always the same result. :/

Comment: I think you should change camera resolution, as some resolutions are 4:3 instead of 16:9 (which normally is for screen). When proportion of camera and screen are equal, it should capture photos as they appear on screen.